# Aggregate heatmap click points

Tags: javascript, jquery, heatmap

I am using **heatmap.js**  version 2 to improve my product usability. I am facing the below scenario.

---

[image]

**Javascript Code**

```
var data = [ {x:100, y:100, value:1}, {x:110,y:110, value:1}, {x:110,y:120, value:1}, {x:130, y:150, value:1}, {x:150, y:160, value:1}, {x:50, y:50}, {x:50, y:50, value:1}];
var heatmap = h337.create({
       container: document.getElementById("overlay"),
       opacity: 0.4,
       radius:30,
       backgroundColor:"rgba(0,0,0,0.4)"
});
for(var i=0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
   heatmap.addData(data[i]);
}
```

If you see this image the color representation shows the most clicked area because of two click happened in same x and y([x:50, y:50], [x:50, y:50]) but the bottom one has more clicks in the radius (30).

**Question**

What is the correct way to aggregate the click points?